# How to make stack bar graph in SVG from JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I was replying to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483145/stacking-svg-rectangles-from-json-data?noredirect=1#) that @markb [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086990/markb) asked but the question got deleted. I am sharing here what I worked out as a solution.

The objective was to convert JSON data into a graph bar like this one:

[image: Target result]

The JSON data was formatted this way:

```
// dummy data
const json = `{ "data": [ 
    { "value": [1, 2, 3, 4] }, 
    { "value": [5, 6, 7, 8] },
    { "value": [9, 0, 1, 2] },
    { "value": [3, 4, 5, 6] } 
] }`,
  dataJSON = JSON.parse(json).data;
```

Comment: @markb if you still need it

Answer (score 1):

I can propose this solution.

```js
// dummy data
const json = `{ "data": [ 
{ "value": [1, 2, 3, 4] }, 
{ "value": [5, 6, 7, 8] },
{ "value": [9, 0, 1, 2] },
{ "value": [3, 4, 5, 6] } 
] }`,
dataJSON = JSON.parse(json).data;

const graphDOM = document.getElementById("graphDOM");

const imageHeight = 100;
const colWidth = 10;
const spaceBetweenCols = 20;

// this will contain the sum for each column
const totalColumns = [];

// this is the highest a column will go
maxValueAllColumns = 0;

// this is the number of columns that will be displayed
nbColumns = 0;


for (line=0; line<dataJSON.length; line++) {
  for (col=0; col<dataJSON[line]["value"].length; col++) {
    if (typeof totalColumns[col] == "undefined") {
      totalColumns[col] = 0;
    }
    totalColumns[col]+=dataJSON[line]["value"][col];
    maxValueAllColumns=Math.max(maxValueAllColumns,totalColumns[col]);
    nbColumns = Math.max(nbColumns, col+1);
  }
}

// ratio
ratioDisplayed = imageHeight / maxValueAllColumns;

// variables
dataContainer = document.getElementById('data-container');
dataItem = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');

html="";
for (col=0; col<nbColumns; col++) {
  stackTo = 0;
  for (line=0; line<dataJSON.length; line++) {
    if (typeof dataJSON[line]["value"][col] != "undefined") {
      rectHeight = Math.round(dataJSON[line]["value"][col] * ratioDisplayed);
      rect_x0 = (spaceBetweenCols+colWidth)*col;
      rect_y0 = 0 + imageHeight - stackTo - rectHeight;
      stackTo += rectHeight;
      
      html += '<rect x="' + rect_x0 + '"y="' + rect_y0 + '"width="' + colWidth + '" height="' + rectHeight + '" fill="rgb(' + (50*line) + ', ' + (50*line) + ', ' + (50*line) + ')"></rect>"';
    }
  }
}

graphDOM.innerHTML = "<svg>" + html + "</svg>";
```

```css
svg {
  max-width: 25em;
  margin: 2em 5em;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="graphDOM"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g id="data-container"></g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it didn't work due to a missing `</svg>`. Added that.

Comment: Javascript should delete everything inside the div anyway, but thanks, it's cleaner. :) I didn't focus on how to display the html the best way, the issue described was more about how to build the graph.